# What is an integrator lens?

Tags: optics

I was looking into how photolithographic mask aligners works and came across this diagram, I am curious as to what an 'integrator' is. It seems like these lenses are used to focus the light beam, am I correct? Is the diagram correct in showing these lenses as being flat or is their curvature simply subtle?

[image: Mask Aligner]

Comment: What is described as an integrator is also called a fly's eye, if it helps to search for helpful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To minimize the influence of the arc spread and its actual position there is a diffusing element placed in the secondary focus of the mask aligner (Integrator 1). The Integrator 1 is followed by the so-called Integrator 2. The Integrator 1 has the function to create a radiation field as uniform as possible at the plane of the Integrator 2. A glass plate with pyramids or lenses on one side is used as Integrator 1 within the standard illumination system.

Here is a close up look to the integrator

[image: flys eye]

It segments the incident spatial distribution. The fly’s eye lens array can be, and often is, split into two separate arrays. In either configuration, the
“lenslets” of the first array or the first surface focuses onto the second. The second is the pupil of an imaging system that images the input faces of the lenslets to the uniform plane. The field lens is the back half of the imaging system which overlays all the images to form a uniform plane.

Comment: As a follow up question, how are fisheye lenses generally used? What is changed by 'breaking the image apart' and reforming it? Does it make scaling it look better?

Comment: Maybe now it's clearer @faissaloo

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now